# Исправить ОЧЕНЬ легкий код

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax

Сразу предупреждаю , слабонервным не читать!
Да учу язык и все время то ошибка с синтаксисом , то с пробелами. Ошибка в функции, перерыл все, но ответа не нашел. Может быть плохо гуглю, а может такой компилятор...

```py
znak = input()
a = input()
b = input()
print (str(znak))
print (int(a))
print (int(b))
if znak == "+":
   plus(1)
elif znak == "-":
   plus(2)
else:
   plus(3)
def plus(znaktyt):
   if znaktyt == 1:
      c = a+b
      print(c)
   break
    elif znaktyt == 2:
      c = a-b
      print(c)
     break
     elif znaktyt == 3:
        print("error")
     break
```

Comment: Плохо, что ошибка, но ещё хуже, что ты умолчал, какая именно.

Comment: Если ошибка что-то вроде ....local before ..., то в начале метода пропиши global a, b. Но так лучше не делать

Comment: Все написал, менял пробелы если кому интересно, то писало что левел не тот, то напишет , что синтакс elif неправильный.

Comment: Вас не смущает что вы что вы написали plus вообще без обьявления чего-либо....?

Comment: Что именно не так?

Comment: А еще не смущает, что заголовок вопроса ни о чем? По нему должно быть понятно, стоит ли дальше читать, терять время на открывание обсуждения. В чем задача? Что выполняет код?  Это и отразите в заголовке

Comment: Если вы получаете сообщение об ошибке - лучше сразу приводить её, можно даже в заголовке, чтобы участники не гадали, что у вас за ошибка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделай функции в самом начале. У тебя стоит функция `plus` внизу, но ты вызываешь её до её объявления. Код же сначала считывается, а после выполняется. Он не может выполнить код, потому что не знает, что ты хочешь от `plus(1)`

Если ты не понял, то приведу пример как нужно все сделать:

```
Функция

    Её внутренности

    return если нужен

А потом уже идешь со своими if и elif:

    И можешь спокойно уже писать plus() с любым числом
```

Проще говоря:

```
def plus(znaktyt):
     if znaktyt == 1:
        c = a+b
        print(c)
И т.д.

if znak == "+":
   plus(1)
elif znak == "-":
   plus(2)
else:
   plus(3)
```

Answer (score 3):

1. С отступами всё плохо. Кое-где они гуляют на плюс-минус один пробел. Кое-где на целый таб промазали.
2. В конструкции if ... elif ... else не нужны break, если условие составлено верно.
3. Функция plus должна быть задана до того, как вы начнёте её использовать.
4. Вы не приводите вводимые данные к числу. Если этого не сделать, то питон будет обрабатывать их как строки, и вместо того, чтобы складывать - просто склеивать вместе. А при вычитании - просто будет ошибка.
5. У вас условие внутри функции и снаружи по сути дублируют одну и ту же логику. Можно это сократить.

Нужно так:

```
znak = input()
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
print (znak)
print (a)
print (b)

def plus(a, b, znak):
    if znak == '+':
        c = a+b
        print(c)
    elif znak == '-':
        c = a-b
        print(c)
    else:
        print("error")

plus(a, b, znak)
```

Answer (score 3):

Вот код, который делает примерно то же самое, но используя иные паттерны:

***Код:***

```py
def func(a, b, sign):
    if sign == '+':
        return a + b

    elif sign == '-':
        return a - b


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = int(input('a: '))
    b = int(input('b: '))
    sign = input('Sign: ')

    res = func(a, b, sign)
    if res:
       print(res)
    else:
        print('Error')
```

**UPD:**
Или вообще так с помощью `eval`:

```py
a = input('a:        ')
operator = input('operator: ')
b = input('b:        ')

print(eval(f'{a} {operator} {b}'))
```

Но это не очень безопасно, будьте бдительны.

Comment: С помощью словаря и функций из пакета [operator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) можно избавиться от `func` :)

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Я б даже сказал, что можно это сделать в несколько строк, например, с помощью `eval`. Но я старался придерживаться кода автора.